# moderators' rudeness and dishonesty

Tags: discussion, support

The moderators of Parenting Stack Exchange suspended my account for 7 days and refuse to give a valid reason. Their putative reasons are that I ignored them telling me to not post, and that I was rude. They did not in fact tell me to not post, plus that just pushes back the question to what the justification for telling me not to post is; this seems rather like arresting someone for resisting arrest. When they claimed that I had been rude, they did not present any examples. Presumably, they were referring to me criticizing an OP for saying that they try every day to get their daughter to cry. I don't consider criticizing terrible parenting to be inappropriate for a parenting site. And if the moderators' position is that criticism is rude, then they're being hypocritical, since they criticized me. Moreover, the OP has not had their accounts suspended despite repeated instances of rudeness, including calling me a "moron" (And, in fact, it was me reporting the OP for this that presumably brought the thread to their attention. Apparently the moderators are punishing people for reporting violations of the rules). I tried to discuss this issue with the moderators, but they refused to respond.

To top it off, the moderators insisted that this was "friendly". No, this isn't "friendly", this is incredibly rude. To recap:

1.They deleted comments that were not a violation of the rules.
2. They accused me of rudeness without offering any quotes that were supposedly rude.
3. They lied about telling me not to post.
4. They refused to respond to my objections to the above.
5. They took no action, that I know of, against someone who was blatantly violating the rules.

I posted this on the general SE Meta, and it was deleted as "duplicate", as if all questions about moderators are the same. I used the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, and got no response.

I think a clear answer is warranted: just what justification do the moderators have for deleting my comments, suspending me, and being wildly rude and dishonest? What rules have  I broken, how, and how can I avoid doing so in the future?

Comment: Got a link to the main meta question? Can't search for it, but as a 10k + there, I can take a look for context.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - The comment thread was deleted, but the question is linked to below.

Comment: I closed this question as off-topic because the answers have already been provided on main meta (hence why your post there was closed), and you are really just ranting. Moderators actions are very visible to other moderators and SE staff - we have checked the records: you were rude, you were warned, you continued to be rude and carry on with actions you had been told not to. Posting here to try and gain sympathy when you are in the wrong won't work.

Comment: "and you are really just ranting." No, I'm asking mods to provide basic justification for their actions. If you're going to suspend someone, you owe it to them to answer basic questions about the reasons. "You were rude" Only if by "rude", you mean "criticizing terrible parenting".  "carry on with actions you had been told not to" That is quite simply a lie. "Posting here to try and gain sympathy when you are in the wrong won't work." I'm not asking for sympathy, I'm simply asking for mods to act with basic decency. " in the wrong " How am in the wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Please note that the only reason your suspension is being publicly discussed is because you have publicly requested an explanation. I don't typically share moderator actions about users with the rest of the community; therefore, any suspension, private mod message, or other "punishment" that another user may or may not have gotten is irrelevant to the suspension you got, and I will not address it.

---

TL;DR -- You harassed another user repeatedly in comments. You can avoid doing so in future by avoiding extended discussion in comments, not accusing other users of traumatizing children, stopping a given behavior when a moderator requests you do so, and reading the rules. These points were covered in the mod messages you have received to date.

---

The sequence of events that led to your suspension was as follows:

1. An exchange of comments with another user over the course of a few hours, during which you repeatedly expressed your opinion that their parenting approach was damaging. There were multiple comments reported in that exchange, some by you and some by another user (third party, actually).

   This exchange was removed, and I commented:

   > Don't use comments for extended discussion, and *definitely* don't use them to be rude to other users.

   Nobody was named in my comment, since I (as noted above) prefer not to single out users. It was intended for both participants as a general warning to (a) not be rude, and (b) stop conversing in comments regardless of politeness.

   Also note that the OP requested you stop commenting multiple times:

   > I would appreciate it if you kept any further comments to yourself
   >
   > I'm asking you ... to stop

   and you didn't stop. That constitutes harassment, which is [against the Be Nice policy](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

   > **Harassment and bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If it keeps up, *disengage* — we'll handle it.
2. 20 hours later, you left another comment on the thread:

   > [other users]'s comments were rude. Mine were not. [other users]'s behavior is deeply disturbing, and anyone who recommends such behavior is not someone whose advice should be listened to. If you're not going to allow criticism of [other users]'s question, then you shouldn't allow the question at all.

   This was removed by me without comment for multiple reasons:

   1. It's meta about the question, not about the answer on which it was posted, which is unfair to the Answer writer. (By "it", here, I mean the portion of your comment: "you shouldn't allow the question at all".)
   2. It constitutes a attempt to extend discussion after everyone was reminded to not use comments for extended discussion.
   3. It continues to posit that the OP's parenting is "deeply disturbing" (harassment, as noted above).

   It's not something that belongs in a comment (ref. [Help Center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)). This would have been a reasonable time to take your complaints to Meta, a question like "Should this question be allowed to stay open" or similar.

   At this point, you were sent (and read) a "mod message" about extended discussion in comments. It included a link to more information about the purpose of comments, suggestions to use Chat for conversation or extended discussion, and a request (with link to help page) to "[treat] others with respect and civility".

   No suspension was included. You did not respond to that message.
3. Three minutes after the StackExchange system records you reading the moderator message about extended discussion in comments, you left a comment on the OP's question:

   > Your daily attempts to traumatize your daughter are deeply disturbing.

   This would violate [Be Nice](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) on its own, but it also continued the pattern of harassment. You therefore received a mildly edited version of the "we've observed some rudeness in your latest activity" template, and a seven day suspension.

   Considering you continued commenting literally right after you'd been told to stop, I felt like you were being pretty rude to me as well. (Also, you said "you saying I have been rude is itself quite rude" and "there is something seriously wrong with you", both indications that a constructive conversation wasn't going to happen.) That isn't the reason you were suspended, but it is the reason I didn't respond to your reply to the second moderator message. You'd already gotten information from me, and it did not seem that repetition would be constructive.

---

Could I have behaved better over this process? Sure. I could have pulled you into a chat room to point out the rules you were breaking, and tried to suggest more constructive ways to put forth your perspective. And I didn't. So I apologize for disengaging in the conversation with you rather than continuing to argue with you.

However, I still feel that your suspension was justified, and I hope that your further participation on Parenting avoids extended commenting and harassing behavior, and brings an understanding perspective rather than confrontational accusations.

Comment: "That constitutes harassment" Posting without someone's permission is not "harassment". If you're just going to make up new definitions for words, I don't see how you can expect people to know how to follow your rules.

Comment: "It's meta about the question, not about the answer on which it was posted" It *is* about the answer. It responded to the answer recommending talking to someone who had shown themselves to be incompetent. "It constitutes a attempt to extend discussion after everyone was reminded to not use comments for extended discussion" It recapitulates a comment directly at the answer, that was deleted for no reason. The only *comment* that it responds to you is your comment. "It continues to posit that the OP's parenting is "deeply disturbing" (harassment, as noted above)." Criticism is not harrassment.

Comment: "Please note that the only reason your suspension is being publicly discussed is because you have publicly requested an explanation." And the reason I am publicly requesting an explanation is that you have refuse to give me a private one. A bit dishonest to pretend that this is my choice of how to handle it.

Comment: Cherry picking sentences to argue with is not going to be particularly constructive.

Comment: "This would violate Be Nice on its own" Only if one interprets "Be nice" as "never disagree with anyone". "continued the pattern of harassment" Again with pretending "harassment" means whatever you say it means. 
"Considering you continued commenting literally right after you'd been told to stop" I was never told to stop commenting. You continuing to make that false claim is more rudeness. You claim that one of the reason that my comment to an answer was deleted was that it responded to the question, but then when I post it as a comment to the question,  you suspend me.

Comment: "(Also, you said "you saying I have been rude is itself quite rude" and "there is something seriously wrong with you", both indications that a constructive conversation wasn't going to happen.)" So when people object to what you say, you refuse to have a conversation with them.  "You'd already gotten information from me" No, I hadn't.

Comment: "not accusing other users of traumatizing children" So when someone traumatizes children, I shouldn't say anything? "stopping a given behavior when a moderator requests you do so" Yet again, I was not told to stop commenting.

Comment: Do you want an _argument_, or an _explanation_? The former will get you suspended a second time, because you're being rude to me _right now_ -- for the latter, see above. (_And_ you're once again having an extended discussion in comments. _Come on._)

Comment: "Cherry picking sentences to argue with is not going to be particularly constructive." I am quoting your claims, then responding to them. That's not "cherry-picking". You're the one refusing to engage in constructive discussion, with your nonsensical accusations.

Comment: I gave you a response. I am not going to give you an argument.

Answer (score 5):

The rudeness appeared in a comment thread under one of the answers to [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/32590/9327).

You're misrepresenting the situation considerably. When someone is being disruptive on the site, and are told by a moderator to stop their disruptive activity but don't, instead accelerating it, there is nothing good coming down the pike.

> I don't consider criticizing terrible parenting to be inappropriate for a parenting site.

We do. We have a policy here that if you disagree with the premise of a question, you walk away/go on to the next question. You don't get to badger the parent.

> if the moderators' position is that criticism is rude, then they're being hypocritical, since they criticized me.

Constructive feedback is not just criticism. It's about how the site operates and should be given some thought during the cooling off period.

> Moreover, the OP has not had their accounts suspended despite repeated instances of rudeness, including calling me a "moron...

The OP was suspended for a longer period than you were. Rudeness is rudeness. It is not tolerated here.

> ...(mods) being wildly rude and dishonest?

As you can see, dishonesty is usually *something someone else does*; it's harder to spot in one's own behavior.

So you can see that your post is riddled with inaccuracies, and this is only the beginning.

Comment: "You're misrepresenting the situation considerably." You fail to identify any misrepresentation, other than my claiming that the OP was not suspended, which was a reasonable inference from them posting afterwards, and therefore was not a deliberate misrepresentation. "When someone is being disruptive on the site, and are told by a moderator to stop their disruptive activity but don't" You are the one misrepresenting. This does not describe my behavior.

Comment: "We have a policy here that if you disagree with the premise of a question, you walk away/go on to the next question." So no criticism of parenting are allowed? "You don't get to badger the parent." More representation. I did not "badger". "Constructive feedback is not just criticism." You're playing word games. My comments were just as much "constructive feedback" as yours were. And accusing me of rudeness is *not* a statement about how the site works, it is criticism, pure and simple. You are being dishonest.

Comment: "So you can see that your post is riddled with inaccuracies" Having an opinion different from yours is not an "inaccuracy". Pretending they are, and saying "You will not believe me anyway." is quite rude

Comment: Granted, I'll remove that last part.

Comment: Your comments here speak to your behavior, as do mine.